# Map component reload when input change

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, next.js13

i'm trying to integrate my NextJs Project with Google Maps, then i had a problem, when i use the map to select a location inside of my form and then i edit the inputs, the map just refresh and delete the ubication selected previously, here is my Location Selector Componet code:

```
// components/LocationSelector.js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Loader } from '@googlemaps/js-api-loader';

const LocationSelector = ({ onLocationSelect }) => {
    const [map, setMap] = useState(null);
    const mapCenter = { lat: -3.9964339532493978, lng: -79.20091423951207 };
    const mapZoom = 14;

    useEffect(() => {
        const loader = new Loader({
            apiKey: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GOOGLE_MAPS_API,
            version: 'weekly',
        });

        loader.load().then(() => {

            const map = new window.google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                center: mapCenter,
                zoom: mapZoom,
            });
            setMap(map);

            var marker;

            function placeMarker(location) {
                if (marker) {
                    marker.setPosition(location);
                } else {
                    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: location,
                        map: map,
                    });
                }
            }

            map.addListener('click', (event) => {
                const selectedLocation = event.latLng.toJSON();
                console.log('Click en el mapa:', selectedLocation);
                placeMarker(event.latLng);
                onLocationSelect(selectedLocation);
            });

        });
    }, [onLocationSelect]);

    return <div id="map" style={{ height: '400px', width: '100%' }} />;
};

export default LocationSelector;
```

And there's my page code:

```
'use client';
import Header from "@/app/components/Header";
import { useState } from 'react';
import { Textarea } from "@nextui-org/react";
import { createEvent } from "@/app/conexion-sw/event_requests";
import LocationSelector from "@/app/components/LocationSelector";
import { set } from "mongoose";
export default function createForm() {
    const [location, setLocation] = useState({ lat: 0, lng: 0 });
    const [eventData, setEventData] = useState({
        title: '',
        date: '',
        description: '',
        images: [
            "url_imagen_3",
            "url_imagen_4"
        ],
        category: [
            "Concierto"
        ],
        participants: [],
        price: 0,
        isFree: true,
        capacity: 0,
        address: '',
        location: {
            lat: 0,
            lng: 0
        },
    });
    const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        const formData = new FormData(event.target);
        const data = Object.fromEntries(formData);
        data.location = location;
        console.log('Datos del formulario:', data);
        createEvent(data).then((res) => {
            console.log("Respuesta del servidor", res);
        }).catch((err) => {
            console.error("Error al crear el evento", err);
        });
    };


    const handleInputChange = (e) => {
        const { name, value } = e.target;
        setEventData({
            ...eventData,
            [name]: value,
        });
    };

    const handleLocationSelect = (selectedLocation) => {
        console.log('Ubicación seleccionada frontend:', selectedLocation);
        setLocation(selectedLocation);
    };

    const handleFileChange = (e) => {
        const { name, files } = e.target;
        console.log('Imágenes seleccionadas:', files);
    };

    return (
        <div className="flex flex-col h-full bg-white-mode-background dark:bg-dark-mode-background items-center justify-center">
            <Header />
            <div className="h-fit w-fit rounded border bg-white-mode-bg-login border-white-mode-border text-white-mode-text dark: bg-dark-mode-bg-login dark:text-dark-mode-text dark:border-dark-mode-border items-center mt-16">
                <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} className="bg-transparent p-4">
                    <h1 className="text-2xl font-bold mb-4 text-center">Crear Evento</h1>
                    <div className="mb-4">
                        <label htmlFor="title" className="block mb-2">
                            Nombre del evento:
                        </label>
                        <input
                            type="text"
                            id="title"
                            name="title"
                            className="bg-transparent p-2 rounded border w-full border-white-mode-border dark:border-dark-mode-border"
                            onChange={handleInputChange}
                            required
                        />
                    </div>

                    <div className="mb-4">
                        <label htmlFor="date" className="block mb-2">
                            Fecha del evento:
                        </label>
                        <input
                            type="datetime-local"
                            id="date"
                            name="date"
                            className="bg-transparent p-2 rounded border w-full border-white-mode-border dark:border-dark-mode-border"
                            onChange={handleInputChange}
                            required
                        />
                    </div>

                    <div className="mb-4">
                        <label htmlFor="description" className="block mb-2">
                            Descripción del evento:
                        </label>
                        <Textarea
                            id="description"
                            name="description"
                            label="Descripción"
                            variant="bordered"
                            placeholder="Ingresa la descripción del evento"
                            className="max-w-xs bg-transparent p-2 rounded border w-full border-white-mode-border dark:border-dark-mode-border"
                            onChange={handleInputChange}
                            required
                        />
                    </div>

                    <div className="mb-4">
                        <label htmlFor="images" className="block mb-2">
                            Imágenes del evento:
                        </label>
                        <input
                            type="file"
                            /*id="images"
                            name="images"
                            */multiple
                            accept="image/*"
                            className="bg-transparent p-2 rounded border w-full border-white-mode-border dark:border-dark-mode-border"
                        //onChange={handleFileChange}}
                        />
                    </div>
                    <LocationSelector onLocationSelect={handleLocationSelect} />


                    <div className="mb-4">
                        <button type="submit" className="bg-blue-500 text-white p-2 rounded w-full">
                            Crear Evento
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Thanks!

I tried to separate the location and not insert it directly into the EventData variable, because I thought maybe the name was a problem, so I updated the location data only when the form is submitted.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution in case it helps someone, the problem was in the component, specifically the instance of the `onLocationSelect` function, since a new instance was created when changing the dependencies, so you have to meomize the function, using `useCallBack` is easy to do, here is the solution:

```js
// components/LocationSelector.js
import React, { useState, useEffect, useCallback } from 'react';
import { Loader } from '@googlemaps/js-api-loader';

const LocationSelector = ({ onLocationSelect }) => {
    const [map, setMap] = useState(null);
    const mapCenter = { lat: -3.9964339532493978, lng: -79.20091423951207 };
    const mapZoom = 14;

    const memoizedOnLocationSelect = useCallback(onLocationSelect, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        const loader = new Loader({
            apiKey: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GOOGLE_MAPS_API,
            version: 'weekly',
        });

        loader.load().then(() => {
            const map = new window.google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                center: mapCenter,
                zoom: mapZoom,
            });
            setMap(map);

            var marker;

            function placeMarker(location) {
                console.log('Marcador en:', location);
                if (marker) {
                    marker.setPosition(location);
                    console.log("1");
                } else {
                    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: location,
                        map: map,
                    });
                    console.log("2");
                }
            }

            map.addListener('click', (event) => {
                const selectedLocation = event.latLng.toJSON();
                console.log('Click en el mapa:', selectedLocation);
                placeMarker(event.latLng);
                memoizedOnLocationSelect(selectedLocation);
            });

        });
    }, [memoizedOnLocationSelect]);

    return <div id="map" style={{ height: '400px', width: '100%' }} />;
};

export default LocationSelector;
```